# Analysis Services not allowing other/remote connections other than localhost

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, authentication

[image]

Analysis services not allowing any connections  except localhost. Authentication box is disabled and only allow windows authentication. How can I connect to different remote analysis servers using sql server authentication.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We always run our Analysis Services on a named server, e.g. AnSrv123, and being run by a Domain Login such as DomainName\ManageAnSRV124.

Regarding connecting to Remote Analysis Servers using SQL Server authentication please note the following.

**Connect from client applications (Analysis Services)**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn141153.aspx

This says, in part: "Authentication is always Windows authentication, and the user identity is always the Windows user who is connecting via Management Studio."

Answer (score 1):

You can't connect to SSAS with SQL authentication. SSAS only uses Windows authentication..

On the server side users must be defined as part of a security role. The role will define what cube privileges you have.

To connect to another server you type the server name in field where it says local host.